# Когда и в каких случаях стоит применять umask?

Tags: c

`umask` задает атрибуты для всего процесса по умолчанию, также при создании файла мы можем указать ему параметры, которые нам необходимы. Если их всегда можно указать, то зачем вообще эта команда? Задать, например, `umask(022)` и потом в `open(...)` пропустить этот параметр? Возможно, пример плохо сформулирован, но я не до конца понимаю назначение этой команды.

Comment: Уже ранее был такой вопрос, неужели было сложно сначала поискать, прежде, чем спрашивать снова ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198623/when-is-umask-useful

Comment: @And видел. Но подтянуть уровень английского хотя бы до понимания через translate за день я не могу. С ним всё плохо. Вот и прошу пояснить по-русски.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `umask` задает атрибуты для всего процесса по умолчанию

Совершенно верно - по УМОЛЧАНИЮ!

> их всегда можно указать

Но только в системном вызове `open()`!

> зачем вообще эта команда?

А как быть в такой ситуации:

```
system("cp file1 file2");
```

Вот здесь и полезны права по умолчанию.